# Custom view changes when changing tab

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-custom-view

My custom view (which is a button) seems to be reinitialized when I change tab and come back to the one where my custom view is.

Before changing tab (when I launch the app):

[image]

After changing:

[image]

Find below the code of my custom view (without custom public methods):

```
public class ButtonView extends RelativeLayout {

    private RelativeLayout mRelativeContainer;
    private TextView mTextViewButton;
    private ImageView mImageViewArrow;
    private DiagonalLayout mDiagonalLayout;
    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayoutDiagonalColor;

    private int mDirection;
    private String mText;
    private float mTextSize;
    private int mTextColor;
    private int mButtonColor;
    private int mObliqueColor;

    public ButtonView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        customLabel(context, null);
        init(context);
    }

    public ButtonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        customLabel(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ButtonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        customLabel(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        switch (mDirection) {
            case DIRECTION_RIGHT:
                inflate(context, R.layout.button_view_right, this);
                break;
            case DIRECTION_LEFT:
                inflate(context, R.layout.button_view_left, this);
                break;
        }
        mRelativeContainer = findViewById(R.id.container);
        mTextViewButton = findViewById(R.id.text);
        mImageViewArrow = findViewById(R.id.arrow);
        mDiagonalLayout = findViewById(R.id.diagonal);
        mRelativeLayoutDiagonalColor = findViewById(R.id.diagonal_color);

        mRelativeContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_button_view);
        setText(mText);
        setTextSize(mTextSize);
        setTextColor(mTextColor);
        setButtonColor(mButtonColor);
        setObliqueColor(mObliqueColor);
    }

    private void customLabel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.ButtonView,
                0, 0);

        try {
            mDirection = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.ButtonView_direction, DIRECTION_RIGHT);
            mText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ButtonView_text);
            mTextSize = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.ButtonView_text_size, 52);
            mTextColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.ButtonView_text_color, getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
            mButtonColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.ButtonView_button_color, getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            mObliqueColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.ButtonView_oblique_color, getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_blue));
        } finally {
            typedArray.recycle();
        }
    }

    private int getPercent(int i, int percent) {
         return i * percent / 100;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int marginTopBottom = getPercent(mTextViewButton.getMeasuredHeight(), 50);
        int marginStartEnd = getPercent(mTextViewButton.getMeasuredHeight(), 70);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewButtonParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mTextViewButton.getLayoutParams();
        textViewButtonParams.setMargins(
                marginStartEnd, marginTopBottom,
                marginStartEnd, marginTopBottom);
        mTextViewButton.setLayoutParams(textViewButtonParams);

        /***************************************************************/

        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mImageViewArrow.getLayoutParams()).width = getPercent(mTextViewButton.getMeasuredHeight(), 60);
        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mImageViewArrow.getLayoutParams()).height = getPercent(mTextViewButton.getMeasuredHeight(), 60);

        switch (mDirection) {
            case DIRECTION_RIGHT:
                ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mImageViewArrow.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, 0, marginStartEnd, 0);

                mDiagonalLayout.getLayoutParams().width = getMeasuredWidth();
                mDiagonalLayout.getLayoutParams().height = getPercent(mTextViewButton.getMeasuredHeight(), 35);

                ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mDiagonalLayout.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(
                        0,
                        marginTopBottom * 2 + mTextViewButton.getMeasuredHeight() - mDiagonalLayout.getLayoutParams().height,
                        0,
                        0);
                break;
            case DIRECTION_LEFT:
                ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mImageViewArrow.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(marginStartEnd, 0, 0, 0);

                mDiagonalLayout.getLayoutParams().width = getPercent(mTextViewButton.getMeasuredHeight(), 60) * 4;
                mDiagonalLayout.getLayoutParams().height = getPercent(mTextViewButton.getMeasuredHeight(), 35);

                ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mDiagonalLayout.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(
                        0,
                        marginTopBottom * 2 + mTextViewButton.getMeasuredHeight() - mDiagonalLayout.getLayoutParams().height,
                        0,
                        0);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea of what happens and I didn't find any proper answers so far.

Comment: Can you show also how you change tabs

Comment: I suggest debugging it with a breakpoint on the line where you set the height of `mImageViewArrow` within `onMeasure`. You might find that `getPercent(mTextViewButton.getMeasuredHeight(), 60)` does not return the value that you are expecting. Also please share the code of your `getPercent` method.

Comment: @Ovidiu I've added `getPercent` function, however I think the problem comes from the fact that `onMeasure` method is called only when the activity is launched and not when you come back to the tab

Comment: @NayMak That is correct - `onMeasure` will not be called again, but `onDraw` will! Is the drawable used on `mImageViewArrow` used anywhere else within the app? For example, if you have 2 ImageViews using the same drawable resource, and apply changes to the drawable within one of the ImageViews, the same changes will be applied to the drawable in the other ImageView as well.

Comment: @NayMak This is possibly what is happening in your scenario as well - when you first open the app, the custom view gets measured and drawn. Another custom view with the same drawable then gets measured within the other tabs. When you return to the first tab, the custom view gets redrawn, using the latest measurement which was from a different view. You could either set the drawable programmatically instead of from XML, after calling `mutate()` on it, or remember the first measured height of the `mImageViewArrow` within the custom view, and reapply it within `onDraw`